# GOOGLE SHEETS - how to automatically display cells horizontally

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, sequence, spreadsheet

This is my first time posting and I hope someone can help.

I am not sure how to word this - here is my best go...

[Please see example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kmb1yMjY081D4ZX5IXjFwN_K370vQ7MruAtcq6-cWaQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Below I explain what I am trying to achieve that corresponds to the spreadsheet:

1. Clients pay a setup fee in a certain month - (B5)
2. I identify through a formula the month that the fee occurs - (C5).
3. There is a certain number of months (B7) after the fees start to roll out based on the fee schedule (Row 3)

**4. DESIRED OUTCOME (Row 12) - I would like a formula that understands that the fee is paid in Month 3, then from Month 7 will roll out the start of the fee schedule from Row 3 (starting from Month 1, automatically)**

Hope this all makes sense - please let me know if I can clarify anything and very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({SPLIT(REPT("0×", C5+B7-1), "×"), SEQUENCE(1, 12, 50, 10)}, 1, 12)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the formula has hard coded the Fee schedule - is it possible to read the values from Row 3 rather than having it hard coded? The reason is the numbers can be dynamic depending on other changes in the sheet.

Comment: Figured it out :) thanks again for your help its very much appreciated - I just added "UNIQUE" instead of sequence in your formula